# Access information from Byte Array using its index

Tags: xcode, arrays, nsdata

I am using  a byte array to store Nsdata of(4840 bytes) and nnow i have to access the data at index of byte array.here is my code .

```
[Bufferdata appendBytes:&data length:len]; 
Byte *byteArray = (Byte *)[data bytes];

for(int i=0;i< sizeof(byteArray);i++)   
**NSLog(@"BYTES %@",[byteArray objectAtIndex:i])**;
```

but it is giving BAD ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `byteArray` pointer you get back from `[data bytes]` is a pointer to raw bytes, not an object pointer. Since it doesn't point to an object, you can't use it to send messages like `[byteArray objectAtIndex:i]`. Instead, you should do something like:

```
for(int i=0;i< sizeof(byteArray);i++)   
    NSLog(@"BYTES %c", byteArray[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks   @Caleb,      ANY IDEA ABOUT REPETITION OF PACKET         -                                                                                         2011-08-17 11:48:29.939[2383:207] BYTES ˇ
2011-08-17 11:48:30.648[2383:207] BYTES ™
2011-08-17 11:48:31.252[2383:207] BYTES U
2011-08-17 11:48:31.763[2383:207] THE RECIEVE QUEUE CONTAING PACKET (
    "<AsyncReceivePacket: 0x532c970>"
)
(BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
[sock receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:1]

Comment: You're using NSLog(), which will naturally print the date and time of each message. NSLog() is not the same as printf().